# Arduino TRE Release Date and Cost

Tags: hardware

I have been awaiting the release date for some time for the Arduino TRE.  So, my question is simple does anyone know the release date or any hints about when it might come out?  Also, what do you think the cost will be?

Comment: Who is making the TRE? LLC or SRL? All the throwing-toys-out-of-cots going on at the moment will most likely delay all new releases of hardware by at least 5 years.

Comment: Looking at the price of the Due, and comparing to BeagleBone or Raspberry Pi, I'm afraid it will be *a lot* more expensive than the latter two.

Comment: @Majenko: I didn't understand what you meant until now...good point! Thats sad. :-(